# Undefined Variables in Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, global-variables, google-tag-manager, breadcrumbs, google-datalayer

I am working on creating a couple of tags in Google Tag Manager and need access to the site breadcrumbs from within either the data layer or the universal variable. I am looking at https://www.lkbennett.com/ site address and was looking at listing pages and product pages.

For example:

https://www.lkbennett.com/New-Arrivals

[https://www.lkbennett.com/product/CDDAPHNEVISCOSEPinkMulti~Daphne-Pink-Rope-Print-Dress-Multi](https://www.lkbennett.com/product/CDDAPHNEVISCOSEPinkMulti%7EDaphne-Pink-Rope-Print-Dress-Multi)

If you inspect the page and search on console you will see what I am talking about.

I can see in our universal variable has breadcrumbs already defined. I tried to add the javascript varible to gtm as universal_variable.page.breadcrumb[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofOSp.png) etc for each part of the breadcrumb however I am getting undefined variables in my preview?

I thought it was due to being an array, but I have done some reading and that appears to be fine. I was confused as per the data layer as it appears to already sit within the datalayer variable, in console?

Any help I would be so grateful. I particularly want to learn rather than have it being done for me if possible. Anyone got any suggestions for further training courses. Do you think I should be learning Javascript, to be able to under google tag manager better?

Thanks Sally

[LKBennett Breadcrumb Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofOSp.png)
[LKBennett Breadcrumb Example with Array Breakdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xa1Vm.png)